# AOP on different classloader classes

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, load-time-weaving

I have an application deployed in jboss. 
In that I have .war(Web application) and .sar(Service layer).
These two are loading by different class loaders.
Now I want to apply AOP on the classes which are sitting in the .sar file from .war file.
We are referring those services(.sar classes) using JNDI in web layer.
Any one please let me know How can I apply AOP on service layer classes from web module.

Comment: It seems like a design issue for me. Why do you want to modify behaviour of Services from Web Layer?

Comment: Basically for every request based on the user locale I want to change the connection propery(NLS language) . But spring jdbc template is not given any approach to set connection properties. So I have wrote an class which is extended from DelegatingDataSource and implementing  from SmartDataSource. So I can get control on connection. So I want to apply that language from web module using aop on that class.

Comment: General hint: If you expect any help here on SO, please provide some sample code. As for the concrete problem at hand, maybe @R4J ist right.